# Export procedural texture to a file

Tags: textures, blender, procedural

Is there a way to export the diffuse map of a procedural texture from blender?

And would it be seamless?

I would like to generate something like a tile material and then export it to a file for use in other 3D software.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily render an image of any procedural texture you setup in blender. This is simply a matter of placing the camera so that it is looking directly at a plane with the texture.

While you should be able to make tileable textures like this, there is no easy formula to do it, it will be a matter of adjusting the texture and camera position until the generated image aligns on the boundaries. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfxUmQIgrB8) should give you some tips on how to achieve that.